# Output JSP variable into JavaScript snippet

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a `varStatus` on my loop, and I would like to send it to a function in js.

This is what I have:

```
onkeyup="clickableButton(this.value, ${newCommentStatus.index})"
```

But `${newCommentStatus.index}` is undefined. How could I send this value??

Thanks ins advance

**EDIT**

```
    <c:forEach items="${threadviewModel.emailToShowList}" var="row" varStatus="status">
    <form:form modelAttribute="commentFieldModel">
<span class="commentInput"><form:input id="commentInput" type="text" path="commentText" size="90" value=" " onkeyup="clickableButton(this.value, ${status.index})"/></span>
                                        <div><input disabled="true" type="submit" id="save-${status.index}" name="_eventId_addComment" value="Save"/></div>
                                    </div>
                            </form:form>
```

Javascript code

```
function clickableButton(text, id) {
            if (text.length > 0)
                document.getElementById("save-" + id).disabled = false;
            else
                document.getElementById("save-" + id).disabled = true;
        }
        ;
```

Comment: Can you post some more code please?

Comment: What is `newCommentStatus`?  Where is `varStatus`? What is the `${}` from, a templating engine?  What loop?  There's no such thing as an "HTML variable".

Comment: It's JSP. The "varStatus" thing gives looping state information, like the index and some flags for "atStart" and "atEnd".  It's for the JSP template engine's "forEach" construct.

Comment: Also there's no reason that won't work.  The "index" is always a number, so that construct would result in a JavaScript numeric constant. I suspect a typo or something. You'll have to post the whole `<c:forEach>` loop for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but you still did not post the complete context for that "onkeyup" handler.

Answer (score 3):

Your `<c:forEach>` calls the variable "status", not "newCommentStatus".

The event handler would look like:

```
... onkeyup="clickableButton(this.value, ${status.index})" ...
```

Also, you can clean up your JavaScript:

```
    function clickableButton(text, id) {
        document.getElementById("save-" + id).disabled = text.length <= 0;
    }
```

Comment: that is exaclty what I am doing. id is undefined

Comment: @BeaGonzalezGutierrez There's no way that can happen, as the index value is a number. You should be debugging this by looking at the generated page as it looks in the browser, not from the JSP source.

Comment: I am using google chrome analyzer and that is what I get. I can not post the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

try the way instead

`onkeyup="clickableButton(this.value, '${newCommentStatus.index}')"`

Answer (score -1):

${newCommentStatus.index} is NOT standard JavaScript.
I suspect that you are using JQuery or something similar: try ${newCommentStatus}.index
This will work with some assumptions.

Comment: It's not jQuery, it's server-side JSP.

Comment: How do you expect it to work with JavaScript than? JSP will generate a page ONCE and then JavaScript will run and process it a number of times. You can only have ONE value generated by JSP in your page, or you can get JSP variable via AJAX

Comment: It's possible to *construct* the JavaScript with the server-side code.

Comment: @Pointy - Is not it exactly what I said? I always thought that "generate" and "construct" has (nearly) the same meaning.

Comment: Well I confess that it's very hard to tell what's intended in this case. You're right of course: if the idea is to somehow *blend* the server- and client-side code, then that's nonsensical.